# MSAL js to show login in webpage than popup & custom redirect uri configuration

Tags: angular, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using `Azure AD B2C UI customization` feature to have my own custom login and signup pages. I could get it work from portal by cicking "**Run Now**" button. But i am not sure how to achieve it with Angular SPA.  I think i can use `msal.js` but it is opening login page in popup.

> Is it possible to have full page redirect for login ?

Also, `msal.js` is taking client host url as default `redirect uri`.

> Is it possible to set custom `redirect_uri` in the MSAL configuration ?

for e.g  this sample [web app](https://login.microsoftonline.com/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1a_sign_up_sign_in_games&client_id=f327751f-477c-4df8-a174-f59786d99d9f&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net%2Fb2c_1a_sign_up_sign_in_games-callback&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fb2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwingtipb2c%2FBilling.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fb2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwingtipb2c%2FMusic.Read&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636483580989775419.ZWFjMTM2MWItZWM0Mi00YThmLTg1YTktM2VkYjVjZTNmMWE2MTA2M2YwY2ItYWRhZC00ZmFmLWE5NmYtOWM0OTg3YTU3Mzk3&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJicmFuZCI6IldpbmdUaXAgR2FtZXMiLCJwbGF5ZXJfcHJvZmlsZV9yZWdpc3RyYXRpb25fbW9kZSI6IkJhc2ljIiwibmJmIjoxNTEyNzYxMjk4LCJleHAiOjE1MTI3NjE1OTgsImlhdCI6MTUxMjc2MTI5OCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2dpbi5taWNyb3NvZnRvbmxpbmUuY29tL2VjMGUyOTcyLTM0MDMtNDY4NS05ODNhLTdjMGI4ZmJmN2Y4Ni92Mi4wLyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd2luZ3RpcGdhbWVzYjJjLmF6dXJld2Vic2l0ZXMubmV0L2IyY18xYV9zaWduX3VwX3NpZ25faW5fZ2FtZXMtY2FsbGJhY2sifQ.tWrElj1r_xYoyp6BMPrw2Bc85G1f6PoMlle37rZkVYQ&state=CfDJ8J2_kzTit_lKm8PaAMPLdfCl-2AKUCyyw5Q_3o6o-h2M18tTwpoWDDPvz6Ob6BDHepaaWJztgpiAcykHaP84WCSTCLfQUb8G2qn3NEBj4yT4ep2KQQbUJ2r5sRVWHyFdBeFpSEFVesCAtEF0Bfbf2Vn2PIOuJNCj_q68_fr2oEc0OWDeMof1M6AGVFOlytNo7Ht5wYnI1LYyAwasWzOt2B_fGb-wzbH-vGJXMmh4cB3mkaAAPg0y1MKI1cGYR4l8sEGVtiGkrCt80mNQilpavz49oZpbNQ9-Re5-UYgI8EO82wE_yokLCdCRRWG1kaAKSBwFt_UewnhIjzzGeZBcYQSkqKfMhCxlXcoxC5T7MYLGcZsRPdhQfjD8eaFqc0xJh-VMtlhxPxF88tTl_imizHI) kind of UX i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use msal library with the sample application provided. The policy url will auto load the custom UI.

```js
  var applicationConfig = {
            clientID: _clientId,
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/B2C_1A_signup_signin_usingAAD", 
            b2cScopes: ["https://{tenant}/api/read", "offline_access"],
            webApi: 'https://localhost:44332/api/tasks',
        };

var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage'});
clientApplication.loginRedirect(applicationConfig.b2cScopes)
```

Comment: how to specify redirect uri..  i have multiple reply urls configured in Azure AD. i need to make sure the redirect uri which i passed from client should be used for redirection.

Comment: You can specify the redirect url as `var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage', loginRedirect: _redirect_url });`

Comment: Thanks Nilesh..  one last thing.. how to pass  response type in this cofig..  e.g  response_type = "token id_token" ? I want both accesstoken and id_token to be returned to redirect uri.