Using @azure/msal-angular and using loginRedirect
I am using azure/msal-angula version 3.0.0-alpha.2.
In my azure application we are given a path localhost://4200/home and in angular also we provide same redirect url.  When we use msalService.loginPopup() it subscribes when we use msalService.loginRedirect().  It is not subscribing and it is not calling the below code when login is successful.  When using msalService.loginPopup() it calls the below code.  After the login successful, it redirects to the home page which we gave in the config.  In the home page we check an authorization guard
 this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
      .pipe(
        filter((msg: EventMessage) =>{ 
          return msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS
        }),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
         console.log(result);
      });


Better to redirect manually this.msalService.loginPopup().subscribe((response:AuthenticationResult)=>{
this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account); // after this write your code for redirect.
})

Hi ansari,
before we using popup but not client want loginredirect

Hi ansari, before we using popup but client want loginredirect

There are already solution given in Stackoverflow. Kindly read the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720996/msal-js-to-show-login-in-webpage-than-popup-custom-redirect-uri-configuration

https://temmyraharjo.wordpress.com/2021/12/31/azure-msal-implement-loginredirect-in-angularcall-crm-action/
